# Seeking open source alternative to File Geodatabase

Tags: python, file-geodatabase, geopandas

I would like to use `geopandas` to work on a large dataset which is provided in Esri's file geodatabase format. I would like to be able to read and write this dataset, unfortunately there are still important difficulties which remain with `fiona` being able to read `FileGDB` format. Here is proof:

- https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/565
- https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/868

I could of course convert everything in the FileGDB to shapefiles, but shapefiles have important limitations when compared with feature classes.

I am looking for a file format which supports the following:

- Read/writeable by geopandas
- Which can handle large datasets containing 10's of millions of records
- Not subject to shapefile limitations
- Easily convertible to and from an Esri FileGDB

Anyone know of an alternative?

Comment: GeoPackage? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoPackage

Comment: This ESRI blog was updated for GeoPackage New Functions in ArcGIS Pro https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/data-management/how-to-use-ogc-geopackages-in-arcgis-pro/

Comment: @Mapperz are there tools in ArcMap which would allow me to simply convert from .gdb to .gpkg in one go?

Answer (score 2):

Yer Geopackages are an SQLite based spatial database and are much more capable than shapefiles.

Have a read here about how to use them with geopandas and fiona
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56165069/can-geopandas-get-a-geopackages-or-other-vector-file-all-layers

Converting to ESRI FileGDB will probably need to be done using ArcPy (or ESRI based python libraries) as its proprietary tech. Arcpy will support Geopackages though, and there is a FeatureClass to FeatureClass conversion that will do the job with a Geopackage input.